# I want to use noCAPTCHA reCAPTCHA without the checkbox

Tags: recaptcha, captcha

Okay, I want to use Google's reCAPTCHA but I don't want the user to click on anything, Just verify that they're not a robot when the page loads. If the visitor is a bot I want to redirect it to a blocking page.

Is it possible? and how can I do it?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. How can you expect to tell with just page load?

Comment: If you don't want the user to click on anything, don't use reCAPTCHA in the first place. There is a myriad of techniques to ensure, that the client probably is a human being. Use one of those instead.

Comment: Google is working on a "invisible" recapatcha: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/comingsoon/index.html

This could be the solution to your problem. Currently the clicking is a necessary part to seperate bots and legitimate users.

Comment: @feeela Are they bullet proof, if so how much accuracy?